# Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly

Tags: java, sonarqube

There is a Sonar Violation:

**Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly**

```
public void setMyArray(String[] myArray) { 
  this.myArray = myArray; 
}
```

**Solution:**

```
public void setMyArray(String[] newMyArray) { 
  if(newMyArray == null) { 
    this.myArray = new String[0]; 
  } else { 
   this.myArray = Arrays.copyOf(newMyArray, newMyArray.length); 
  } 
}
```

But I wonder why ?

Comment: Umm...that solution didn't work for me, actually. Sonar still picks it up and complains about it, despite making a copy.

Comment: @ndtreviv so how you solved it?

Comment: @ndtreviv: I was having this issue as well, and this error will not go away if the name of the local variable supplied to the method is the same as the instance variable you are storing. Make sure they are different, and the above solution should work. 

I found this out through the following [link](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Security-Array-is-stored-directly-weirness-td3632714.html)

Comment: Java definitely should invent `const` to avoid copying const data forced by this d*** rule.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's complaining that the array you're storing is the same array that is held by the caller. That is, if the caller subsequently modifies this array, the array stored in the object (and hence the object itself) will change.

The solution is to make a copy within the object when it gets passed. This is called **defensive copying**. A subsequent modification of the collection won't affect the array stored within the object.

It's also good practice to normally do this when returning a collection (e.g. in a corresponding `getMyArray()` call). Otherwise the receiver could perform a modification and affect the stored instance.

Note that this obviously applies to all mutable collections (and in fact all mutable objects) - not just arrays. Note also that this has a performance impact which needs to be assessed alongside other concerns.

Comment: I can see the reason.... what if I deliberately want the caller and its target holding the same copy?

Comment: That's a design decision. But I think it's important to understand *who* owns this data, and how (if necessary) you inform objects holding it that it's changed. It's quite reasonable in set of components closely-related to pass collections around without defensive copying. But at some point there'll be a boundary at which you need to protect yourself (e.g. plugging into a 3rd pary or clients' code)

Comment: surely the OP *is* making a defensive copy with `this.myArray = Arrays.copyOf(newMyArray, newMyArray.length);`?

Comment: Also i dont understand why it is just showing arrays. Because, in a bean we will have custom objects and same problem (caller will hold the same copy and if he changes, it will affect internally) can occur, but it is not complaining.

Comment: @Manoj probably because sonar doesn't know if the object is mutable or not. With an immutable object this is no concern that some other class can unexpectedly change the object's state. Arrays cannot be immutable so sonar knows to flag them all the time

Answer (score 22):

It's called defensive copying. A nice article on the topic is ["Whose object is it, anyway?"](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp06243/index.html) by Brian Goetz, which discusses difference between value and reference semantics for getters and setters.

Basically, the risk with reference semantics (without a copy) is that you erronously think you own the array, and when you modify it, you also modify other structures that have aliases to the array. You can find many information about defensive copying and problems related to object aliasing online.

Comment: thanks mate, def a up vote. can you make a small example, or compress the reason in 50 words?

Comment: @ewernli : The link was broken, Please fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue:

> **Security - Array is stored directly      The user-supplied array**
>   **'palomitas' is stored directly.**

my original method:

```
public void setCheck(boolean[] palomitas) {
        this.check=palomitas;
    }
```

fixed turned to:

```
public void setCheck(boolean[] palomitas) { 
      if(palomitas == null) { 
        this.check = new boolean[0]; 
      } else { 
       this.check = Arrays.copyOf(palomitas, palomitas.length); 
      } 
}
```

Other Example:

> **Security - Array is stored directly      The user-supplied array**

```
private String[] arrString;

    public ListaJorgeAdapter(String[] stringArg) {      
        arrString = stringArg;
    }
```

Fixed:

```
public ListaJorgeAdapter(String[] stringArg) {  
    if(stringArg == null) { 
      this.arrString = new String[0]; 
    } else { 
      this.arrString = Arrays.copyOf(stringArg, stringArg.length); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To eliminate them you have to clone the Array before storing / returning it as shown in the following class implementation, so noone can modify or get the original data of your class but only a copy of them.

```
public byte[] getarrString() {
    return arrString.clone();
}
/**
 * @param arrStringthe arrString to set
 */
public void arrString(byte[] arrString) {
    this.arrString= arrString.clone();
}
```

I used it like this and Now I am not getting any SONAR violation...

Comment: for using clone() in user defined array you will need to implement cloneable interface than only it will work else it will throw error

Answer (score 2):

It's more ease than all of this. You only need to rename the method parameter to anything else to avoid Sonar violations.

http://osdir.com/ml/java-sonar-general/2012-01/msg00223.html

```
public void setInventoryClassId(String[] newInventoryClassId)
    {                
            if(newInventoryClassId == null)
            {
                    this.inventoryClassId = new String[0];
            }
            else
            {
                    this.inventoryClassId = Arrays.copyOf(newInventoryClassId, newInventoryClassId.length);
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To go the defensive-implementation-way can save you a lot of time.
In Guava you get another nice solution to reach the goal: ImmutableCollections

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained

Answer (score 0):

There are certain cases where it is a design decision and not missed out. In these cases, you need to modify the Sonar rules to exclude it so that it doesn't show such issues in report.