# java: implications other than security when constructor stores user-supplied array directly

Tags: java, arrays, security, sonarqube

I've run Sonar on a project at work and found a violation 'The user-supplied array is stored directly'.
 So looking a little deeper into what that means exactly I came across lots of stuff discussing it from security perspective ([for example...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580948/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly)). So when I read or hear 'security' I'm thinking malice, cracking, data breach and other grave consequences.
But I wonder what else could go wrong, especially in a load balance environment. Would this be a reason to worry about data contamination across sessions? One customers order data getting corrupted with someone else's details, etc?

Comment: That would depend on _exactly_ how the class works and how it is called.  However, it is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Looks to me like just a bean, Serializable, no biz logic in it, appears to be used in a web services context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should consider this rule as very important if you're exposing a Java API to the rest of the world. The link you provided perfectly explains why (a consumer of your API would be able to change the array at any time if you don't clone it).

If violations occur in your internal implementations (that no one else will ever touch or use), you can lower the severity of the violations as there's no risk that a third-party code can modify the array. However, don't forget that code lives and evolves, and some day even your internal classes may be exposed to the rest of the world.