# Security - Array is stored directly - String [][]

Tags: java, arrays, sonarqube

I did not see an anwser anywhere about this specific Sonar violation in the case of an array of an array.

**Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly**

Code with problem :

```
public void setData(String[][] data) {  
    if(data == null) { 
        this.data = new String[0][];
    } else { 
        String[][] dataCopy = new String[data.length][];
        System.arraycopy(data, 0, dataCopy, 0, data.length);
        this.data = dataCopy;
    }
```

I cannot used the following solution because of my java version :

```
public void setData(String[][] data) {  
    if(data == null) { 
        this.data = new String[0][0];
    } else { 
        this.data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length); 
    } 
}
```

Any suggestions to solve this issue ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580948/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly

Comment: Currently, you're simply copying the original `String[]` array references into a new `String[][]`. You need to do a deep copy, i.e. also cloning those inner `String[]` before placing them into the outer `String[][]`.