# Security - Array is stored directly

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

I even refered : [Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580948/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly)

My code is as --->

```
    public final void setSelectedObjectsList(final ScheduleDTO[] selectedObjectsList) 
               //      Security - Array is stored directly    
               //The user-supplied array 'selectedObjectsList' is stored directly.      
{
            if (selectedObjectsList != null) {
                this.selectedObjectsList = selectedObjectsList.clone();
            } else {
                this.selectedObjectsList = null;
            }
        }
```

This is already taking care of defensive copy wonder why sonar is yelling at me right at function parameter.

This not not duplicate as 
[Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580948/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly)

Again, Thank-you for your hyelp and time.

Comment: can you post what is `selectedObjectsList.clone()` doing?

Comment: @Farlan: selectedObjectsList is a Java array. It clones the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what Sonar is thinking but defensive shallow copying with `clone()` should work fine for arrays, as would `Arrays.copyOf` and `System.arrayCopy()`.

On the other hand, since you are already calling the array a list: `selectedObjectsList`, you could also make it an actual list and refactor a bit:

```
public final void setSelectedSchedules(List<ScheduleDTO> selectedSchedules) {
    this.selectedSchedules = selectedSchedules != null ? new ArrayList<ScheduleDTO>(selectedSchedules) : null;
}
```

Comment: +1. And while you're at it, using null arrays or lists is a bad practices. These should never be null. Empty, yes. Null, no.