# Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly when using byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, sonarqube

I did come across the following 2 posts about a similar issue
[Sonar Violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580948/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly) and
[Sonar Violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903602/security-array-is-stored-directly)
But, my problem is with `byte[]`

Following is the code snippet for which I get this warning in Sonar

```
public void setValue(byte[] value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

I looked at the solutions and made the following changes

```
public void setValue(byte[] value) {
    if(value == null) {
        this.value = new byte[0];
    } else {
        this.value= Arrays.copyOf(value, value.length); 
    }
}
```

Even then, I get the same Security violation warning in Sonar.
Am I getting this warning because it is `byte[]` and byte arrays need to be handled differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following to resolve the issue with byte[]

```
value.clone()
```