# error with byte[] using clone and Arrays.copyOf

Tags: java, spring, arrays, sonarqube

I was trying to solve "Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly", and i've been searching and i found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378449/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly-when-using-byte). I've tried it but it simply wont work, giving `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

The method is very simple

```
public void setData( byte[] data) {
    this.data= data;
}
```

and i tried:

```
public void setData( byte[] data) {
    this.data= Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
}
```

and also

```
public void setData( byte[] data) {
    this.data= data.clone();
}
```

Could someone please explain to me why this is happening?
Thank you.

**EDIT**

I tried

```
public void setData( byte[] data) {
    if(data!= null){
        this.data= data.clone();
    }

}
```

and it worked! I am really confused since this method will only be called when i have something to write, so i not possible for it to be null.

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-1" org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Exception occurred inside setter of com.project.hibernate.Clients.data
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4509)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1107)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:963)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at com.project.hibernate.dao.impl.ClientsDaoImpl.findAllClients(ClientsDaoImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.findAllClients(Unknown Source)
    at com.project.bsl.client.InMemoryClientInfo.initOperate(InMemoryClientInfo.java:104)
    at com.project.bsl.client.InMemoryClientInfo$1.run(InMemoryClientInfo.java:117)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:65)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.project.hibernate.Clients.setData(Clients.java:156)
```

Comment: Can you please post the COMPLETE error message and some of the stacktrace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't the error pretty much explain it? `NullPointerException`. Your method is being called with a `null` argument. Your method calls `clone()` on `null`. You can't do that. You have to check for `null` as you do in the version that works, so, do that. Your method still isn't correct though since it fails to set the field to `null` when the argument is `null`.

Comment: The thing is, this error happens when i launch the application, so this method is not called unless there is something in the database, and if there is its not null! Thats why i don't understand the error...

Comment: Hibernate may be initializing the state of the object. Or maybe you do have an empty field somewhere.