# Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly - trouble with byte[] and clone()

Tags: java, arrays, sonarqube

I found answer in [Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580948/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly)
and
[Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly when using byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378449/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly-when-using-byte)

Following is the code snippet for which I get this warning in Sonar

```
byte[] imageBytes;
public DisplayWebThumb(byte[] imageBytes) {
        super(null);
        this.imageBytes = imageBytes;
    }
```

I looked at the solutions and made few changes.

 From this answer [Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580948/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly) , I made this changes

```
byte[] imageBytes;

public DisplayWebThumb(byte[] imageBytes) {
    super(null);
    if(imageBytes == null){
        this.imageBytes = new byte[0];
    }else {
        this.imageBytes = new byte[imageBytes.length];
        System.arraycopy(imageBytes, 0, this.imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
    }
}
```

From this answer [Sonar Violation: Security - Array is stored directly when using byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378449/sonar-violation-security-array-is-stored-directly-when-using-byte) , I made this changes

```
byte[] imageBytes;  
public DisplayWebThumb(byte[] imageBytes) {
    super(null);
    if(imageBytes == null){
        this.imageBytes = new byte[0];
    }else {
        this.imageBytes = imageBytes.clone();
    }
}
```

All the solutions still give me warning in SonarQube.

Comment: Hi - I've marked as a duplicate since you've detailed the answer elsewhere on SO

Comment: @BrianAgnew The other answers apparently did not fix his problem.

Comment: @BrianAgnew I looked at the solutions but still get the warning .. please look my question carefully.

Comment: I've reopened, but you might want to rephrase