# The user-supplied array is stored directly

Tags: java, arrays, sonarqube

I have refered : [Security - Array is stored directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903602/security-array-is-stored-directly?answertab=active#tab-top).

My code is as

```
public IndexBlockAdapter(String[] itemStr) {
    if(itemStr == null) { 
        this.itemStr = new String[0]; 
    } else { 
        this.itemStr = Arrays.copyOf(itemStr, itemStr.length); 
    }
}
```

But Sonar still picks it up and complains about "Array is stored directly", despite making a copy. I am very confused.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

```
Arrays.copyOf does a shallow copy.
```

It just copies the references and not the actual values.
The following code will print all `true` which proves the fact

```
String [] str1 = {"1","2","3"};

    String [] str2 = Arrays.copyOf(str1, str1.length);
    for (int i=0;i<str1.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(str1[i] == str2[i]);

    }
```

Instead, if you use the following code, you will do a deep copy, and you should be good

```
String [] str3 = new String[str1.length];
for (int i=0;i<str1.length;i++) {
    str3[i] = new String(str1[i]);
}
for (int i=0;i<str1.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(str1[i] == str3[i]);
}
```

Comment: Although this might be the reason, why the copy mechanism is complained about, a shallow copy is still enough. Keep in mind: _String is immutable_.

Comment: Thanks！I think using `System.arrayCopy()` or `Object.clone()` can also do a deep copy, which is more simple. @Hirak

Comment: Finally, I find the real reason is that name of the parameter can not be the same as the instance variable. When I changed the parameter name  to `itemArr`, the warning disappeared .

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
 public IndexBlockAdapter(String[] newItemStr) {
 if(newItemStr == null) { 
    this.itemStr = new String[0]; 
 } else { 
    this.itemStr = Arrays.copyOf(newItemStr, newItemStr.length); 
 }
}
```