# Security - Method returns internal array - Sonar security warning - even when I am returning a clone

Tags: java, security, sonarqube

The below return statement gives me a Sonar security warning even when I am not returning the original array but a clone of it.

What is the "correct" way to do this?

```
public String[] getList() {
        return list!=null? list.clone():null;
}
```

Comment: Please edit in the text of the warning that's given.

Answer (score 0):

Edited my previous answer for some obvious errors :)

List.clone() doesn't work because it returns a shallow copy of the list. So basically it just returns the reference to the original list. We don't want that here. What we want is a brand new array that doesn't have the same reference to be returned.
For that the best idea will always be to create a new array and run a for loop like this:

```
String[] newArr = new String[list.length];
int i = 0;
for (String s : list) {
    newArr[i++] = s
}
```

If you wanna know why this is the issue, refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11581068/9442047) :)