# How to fix the PMD violation ArrayIsStoredDirectly?

Tags: java, pmd

I had a method which generated the PMD violation ArrayIsStoredDirectly:

```
public void setFoo(Object[] foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

This is understandable - I need to clone the array. So I replaced it with:

```
public void setFoo(Object[] foo) {
    if (foo == null) {
        this.foo = null;
    } else {
        this.foo = new Object[foo.length];
        System.arraycopy(foo, 0, this.foo, 0, foo.length);
    }
}
```

However, I'm still getting the ArrayIsStoredDirectly violation!

I'm really not sure why this is. Maybe something in the [ArrayIsStoredDirectly](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/pmd/pmd/4.3/net/sourceforge/pmd/rules/sunsecure/ArrayIsStoredDirectly.java) class is still being picked up incorrectly?

I know I could just suppress the warning, but this doesn't seem like too much of a special case. What is the correct way to fix this violation?

Comment: Just call `foo.clone()`. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11580948/1743880) is relevant.

Comment: @Kidburla, please submit this as a bug to PMD, they should fix it.